# Require Password to Open Access Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a few forms in my Access database that only a few team members should be using I wrote the following to password-protect those forms, but if you enter the wrong password or hit cancel on the pop-up, it will open the form anyway.

How can I prevent Access from loading the form unless you enter the correct password?

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strMsg As String

    Beep
    strMsg = "This function requires a password." & vbCrLf & vbLf & "Please see your manager for assistance."
    strInput = InputBox(Prompt:=strMsg, title:="Password:")
    If strInput = "administrator" Then 'password is correct
        DoCmd.OpenForm "AddNewRule"
    Else 'password is incorrect
        MsgBox "Incorrect Password!" & vbCrLf & vbLf & "Please see your manager for assistance", vbCritical, "Invalid Password"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: DoCmd.Close acform, "FORMNAME"

Comment: Thank you, I added this and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Load`, use the `Open` event:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
```

There you can set `Cancel = True`, then the form won't be opened.

But note that if you open the form from somewhere else with `DoCmd.OpenForm`, it will raise an error that you need to trap or ignore.

---

Note that `DoCmd.OpenForm "AddNewRule"` in the success case is wrong, you are already opening the form.